# How can I convert string to list

Tags: django, forms, list, field

I use python djanggo for web development.
I got an list from input forms, and I saved the list in my djanggo text fields. Then, I brought it from database and print it.

I save the list like that

> [{'question': 'dsasda', 'type': 'ShortAns',},{'question': 'dsads',
>   'type': 'MultipleCho','answer': ['asdadsasd',]},]

And then, I brought it in view like that

```
survey_list = json.loads(survey.questions)
```

I showed it in template, so

```
{{ survey_list.0 }}
```

But it print out only

> [

how can I solve this problem

Comment: Can you say what you're expected result is? Is is `{'question': 'dsasda', 'type': 'ShortAns',}`?

Comment: yes, I expect result like that

Comment: What is `survey.questions` equal to?

Comment: Can you provide the final result format from this input?

Comment: `survey,questions` is equal to 'questions' textfield in 'survey' model, and final result format from input is  json format using `json.dumps`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval(survey.questions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jsonfield. You dont have to convert anything in this case.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import JSONField   
field_name = JSONField(default=list, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Field_name')
```